# Onclick not working for javascript function which takes function as argument?

Tags: javascript, html

Code

**html**

```
<button onclick="getUserIP(function(ip))">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

**script**

```
/**
 * Get the user IP throught the webkitRTCPeerConnection
 * @param onNewIP {Function} listener function to expose the IP locally
 * @return undefined
 */
function getUserIP(onNewIP) { //  onNewIp - your listener function for new IPs
    //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var pc = new myPeerConnection({
        iceServers: []
    }),
    noop = function() {},
    localIPs = {},
    ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
    key;

    function iterateIP(ip) {
        if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
        localIPs[ip] = true;
    }

     //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createDataChannel("");

    // create offer and set local description
    pc.createOffer(function(sdp) {
        sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
            if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
            line.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
        });
        
        pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
    }, noop); 

    //listen for candidate events
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) {
        if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
        ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
    };
}

// Usage

getUserIP(function(ip){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Got your IP ! : '  + ip + " | verify in http://www.whatismypublicip.com/";
});
```

and Demo [jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzeL40d2/)

I'm trying to get private ip of end-user who clicks on this button.

As I run the code, it gives me no output. Basically I don't know the syntax to call a js function which takes function as an argument. Thanks.

**update**

```
<button id="a" onclick=(function(ip)
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = + ip;
})();> Clickme </button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

**error**

`"<a class='gotoLine' href='#41:20'>41:20</a> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"`

Comment: `function(ip)` is not a valid function definition and will throw a SyntaxError. If you really want to define the callback within the onclick attribute try this: `function(ip) { /* your code */ }`

Comment: @subarachnid is right, `onclick="getUserIP(function(ip))` makes no sense, as `getUserIP`'s parameter needs to be an actual function.

Comment: @subarachnid i tried but it gives me error pls see code above

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call the `getUserIP` function and you'll also have to put the attribute value in quotes (`"..."`). For the `('demo')` part you then have to use single quotes. Try this:

```js
// just a demo function (you can ignore this)
const getUserIP = f => f("it works!")
```

```html
<button id="a" onclick="getUserIP(function(ip) {
   document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ip;
});"> Clickme </button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```